# Recyclerview and D-pad navigation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, d-pad

I'm developing an app that needs to use D-pad navigation in a `RecyclerView`. My problem is that although I set `android:focusable=true` in the `items.xml`(news_items), it doesn't seems to work.

My question is: **how should I implement D-pad navigation in a `RecyclerView`?**

The `RecyclerView` is inside the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=":( \n No news available"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fsn_emty_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

news_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/news_ripple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:background="?attr/colorAccent"

                />


            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/ni_margin"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                    tools:text="Titulo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFecha"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    tools:text="Fecha" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPublisher"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    tools:text="Publisher" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: This is the focus order I'am receiving now:
The red color is the focus order I'am getting now, when I click one time from the tab to down, the `RecyclerView`(the entire reycclerview) gets the focus, one more click down and the AdMob(showed in black) get the focus. The blue arrow is what I want inside the RecyclerView

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to focus news items which is in `Recycler View` right ?

Comment: yes, new items is the layout of each item inside the Recyclerview. I want to be able to traverse the items in the Recyclerview throught D-pad

Comment: Look here [My answer from another post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330058/how-to-support-dpad-controls-for-recyclerview/41763188#41763188)

Comment: @CarlosHernándezGil What was the solution in your case?

Comment: @sam_k Add this to the recycler view as you can see in the accepted answer: android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"

Comment: I did it's not working at all :(

Comment: @CarlosHernándezGil In my case the focus moves around the items but it doesn't announce the content description. What do you think it could be the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" solved my problem

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
             />
```

Comment: And don't forget Make root view of your item layout android:focusable="true"